# sas penultimate &syserrortext

Tags: sas, 4gl

How can I get the penultimate &syserrortext?

```
%if %length(&syserrortext) ne 0 %then %do;
```

because I suppose `%abort cancel;` overrides me an error that interests me.

thanks for help, aola

Comment: Can you expand a little?  Show some example code that generates and error and how you want to use it.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to manually store them in some sort of variable array after each step executed.

On a less-related note, I'd seriously reconsider your approach if you have this requirement.  IMO, as soon as any error is encountered, jobs should be stopped.  Having jobs continue after an error has occurred is risky as there are too many things in an unknown state.  I would rather have jobs produce no results at all, then to produce incorrect results.

If SAS provided a nicer approach to error handling where error conditions could be handled nicely then I'd definitely consider alternatives, but unfortunately SAS's approach to error handling is basically non-existent.